# DI into a Requirement/Policy in ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm looking for a way to program a custom authorization filter in ASP.NET 5 as the current implementation relies in Policies/Requirements which in turn rely solely in the use of Claims, thus on the umpteenth and ever-changing Identity System of which I'm really tired of (I've tried all it's flavors).

I have a large set of permissions (over 200) which I don't want to code as Claims as I have my own repository for them and a lot faster way to be check against it than comparing hundreds of strings (that is what claims are in the end).

I need to pass a parameter in each attribute that should be checked against my custom repository of permissions:

```
[Authorize(Requires = enumPermission.DeleteCustomer)]
```

I know this is not the most frequent scenario, but I think it isn't an edge case. I've tried implementing it in the way described by @leastprivilege on his magnificent post "The State of Security in ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6: Authorization", but I've hit the same walls as the author, who has even opened an issue on the ASP.NET 5 github repo, which has been closed in a not too much clarifying manner: [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/297)

Any idea of how to achieve this? Maybe using other kind of filter? In that case, how?

Comment: where exactly is the problem ? That Dependencies are not resolved or that the parameter is not set?

Comment: The problem is that I can't figure out how to pass the Arguments as an array of objects and then get them inside the filter... In previous versions it was done by creating a public property on the filter itself with the same name as the parameter you were passsing (as described above) but now I have to pass an object array...

Comment: This is the problem with the new authorize filter, although the intention of the questions was to ask for any implementation achieving this with policies/requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is an example of how you can achieve this scenario:

Let's assume you have a service called `IPermissionStore` which validates if a given user has the required permissions specified on the attribute.

```
public class MyCustomAuthorizationFilterAttribute : Attribute, IFilterFactory, IOrderedFilter
{
    private readonly Permision[] _permissions;

    public MyCustomAuthorizationFilterAttribute(params Permision[] permissions)
    {
        _permissions = permissions;
    }

    public int Order { get; set; }

    public IFilterMetadata CreateInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var store = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPermissionStore>();

        return new MyCustomAuthorizationFilter(store, _permissions)
        {
            Order = Order
        };
    }
}

public class MyCustomAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter, IOrderedFilter
{
    private readonly IPermissionStore _store;
    private readonly Permision[] _permissions;

    public int Order { get; set; }

    public MyCustomAuthorizationFilter(IPermissionStore store, params Permision[] permissions)
    {
        _store = store;
        _permissions = permissions;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        // Check if the action has an AllowAnonymous filter
        if (!HasAllowAnonymous(context))
        {
            var user = context.HttpContext.User;
            var userIsAnonymous =
                user == null ||
                user.Identity == null ||
                !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

            if (userIsAnonymous)
            {
                Fail(context);
            }
            else
            {
                // check the store for permissions for the current user
            }
        }
    }

    private bool HasAllowAnonymous(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        return context.Filters.Any(item => item is Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization.IAllowAnonymous);
    }

    private void Fail(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}

// Your action
[HttpGet]
[MyCustomAuthorizationFilter(Permision.CreateCustomer)]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    //blah
}
```

Comment: I don't have very clear if this is in a correct ASP.NET 5 fashion but this works indeed... I accept this answer however, could you tell me if your example is relying in old functionality that could be deprecated in short?

Comment: You can take a look in the github repo for samples related to `IFilterFactory` (for example: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/FormatFilterAttribute.cs#L16)...since ASP.NET 5 is still in `beta`, I cannot tell for sure that things wouldn't change

Comment: If you use `IAuthorizationFilter`, please implement `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` too, I had problem with it